# Why can't I store the return value from xmllint --xpath?

Tags: xml, shell, xpath, sh, xmllint

I tried

```
var = $(xmllint --xpath 'string(//datatype)' dataReport_2.xml)
```

which seems not to work.

It only stores a string value of this whole command into a variable. Is there any way to store this value into a variable?

Comment: First, please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Second, try the command without string() first because <datatype> may not have a text node.

Comment: Luis Muñoz Hi, I basically try with or without the parentheses which still does not work. Yes, this xml does contain this text node.

Comment: In `sh`, you can't put spaces around `=` in an assignment.

Comment: edit you question, add errors if any, add more detail to your code. Again, read the link in my previous comment please.

Comment: Please prefer asking one question per post. StackOverflow works better that way (for example, if you ask two separate questions in one post, you can't accept two answers)

Comment: that other guy yeah, I will open another post, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't put spaces or any kind of white-space characters around `=`, so try this:

```
var=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(//datatype)' dataReport_2.xml)
```